# Username capitalization

Tags: credentials, credentials-manager

Is capitalization of user-name important?

In what scenarios it is, and why? (can it be changed locally)

I am thinking about difference between Win Xp and Win 7,8, and Wi-Fi connection?

Comment: "Important" in what way?  Windows doesn't care about case in user names: "UserName" is the same as "username".   All other programs, web sites, etc. will have their own rules if case matters or not.  Anyhow, what's your actual, specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows usernames are case *insensitive*.  That means apples = ApPleS

As Im sure everyone knows, passwords are case *sensitive*.  password =/= PassWord

As far as I know, this can not be changed.  It would cause a massive amount of problems if it could.  I dont even think Windows Services for Unix makes names case sensitive.